# How to Recover Data from Harddisk after formating using dd command

Tags: hard-drive, backup, format, restore, dd

How do I recover data from an external hard disk? I used the `dd` command by mistake on the disk. Specifically, I used:

```
dd if=xyz.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Please help me retrieve the lost data.

Comment: Depending on how bad you need to get data back, can do a lot of reading on how to use testdisk or send it away to a data recovery company(can be expensive).  Stop using drive.

Comment: Iso is of 4.5gb file. Hard disk is 1tb. I already tried testdisk. But I don't see any information on harddrive. The information on drive is badly needed.

Comment: @karel i will work on ur link to see if I can recover anydata

Answer (score 0):

You could try testdisk

`$sudo aptitude install testdisk`

and launch by

`$testdisk`

I suppose that you could recover some data in the HDD, but for sure not all of it, because the data of the ISO you wrote on it by accident overwrote the original data.